# Was the scene in Episode IV about Han Solo and a human Jabba, in the Original movies?

Tags: star-wars

Ok, what I mean is that I don't recall and I can't seem to find it anywhere, is if the scene with **Declan Mulholland** acting as **Jabba** was in the final cut from the original Ep. IV or if it was cut (for resources problems) and then used in the later special editions with new fx, and the CGI **Jabba**?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The original scene with Jabba as a human was filmed for *A New Hope*, but George Lucas originally never intended Jabba to be a human.

He explained the reasoning for the cut on the *Behind the Magic* CD-ROM. From [an article about it](https://web.archive.org/web/20140928112036if_/http://secrethistoryofstarwars.com/jabba.html):

> "When I first shot the scene with Jabba the Hutt, I knew I was going to create some kind of stop-motion creature...I had to have somebody--an actor--play the part so Harrison had someone to play against, so we just picked a big guy and put him in a fuzzy vest. I, at that point, felt that he may be a character somewhat like Chewbacca, a big furry character. We shot that. As we were cutting the movie, [we] realized relatively quickly that we didn't have the time or the money to actually shoot that scene [the stop-motion optical]. That ILM was pressed way beyond what it could pull off as it was. So I had to abandon that sequence pretty early on. I had to cut back on special effects shots and that sort of thing because ILM just couldn't handle it."

As the article goes into, the statement doesn't hold up to complete scrutiny, but the possible explanation is that he shot the scene anyways, but that it ended up being largely unnecessary. The footage with Jabba as a human was cut from the original theatrical cut and original home versions of the film.

With the Special Edition, a number of scenes were [edited or added back in](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases), including the docking bay scene, now with a (less than good) CG Jabba.

Comment: I'm sure I heard an interview with Lucas where in addition to the above he stated that the scene with Greedo is almost word-for-word the same so both couldn't stay in the movie anyway, although that didn't stop him putting it back in for the special editions.

Comment: "As the article goes into, the statement doesn't hold up to complete scrutiny, but the possible explanation is that he shot the scene anyways, but that it ended up being largely unnecessary. " - the way I read it, the issue with capacity was the special effects creation, not the live action, so the live action part got shot but had to be dropped afterward due to ILM not being able to add in the intended Jabba effect over the stand-in human actor.

Comment: @Moo The article goes into the fact that it wasn't shot in a way that a practical alien Jabba could have been added in. Add in the comment about being a "wonderful human being" , which may or may not have been meant as ironic, and I get where they're coming from.

Comment: ...Han Solo has a NON-ironic way of speaking?

Comment: You may want to add a final note that the process continued, with later versions of the Special Edition (including the full trilogy set) having a much, much better CG version of Jabba inserted. Lucas likes to treat his movies as a living document...

Comment: As I recall, there was another issue: in the filmed scene, Han walks all the way around the human representing Jabba with no one thinking about Jabba having a long, think tail. Thus, the special effects would need to include not only replacing the human with Jabba, but also making Han rise up while walking over the tail. I believe this may have been the straw that broke the camel's back in terms of using the scene in the original production. This change _was_ part of the "Special Edition" scene.